# What is the best way to align text at the center of the HTML

Tags: html, winforms

What is the best way to align text at the center of the HTML (both horizontally and vertically aligned) to represent it in the `WebBrowser` control in Windows Forms? Is there any way to do it at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
.centered {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -(50/2)px;
    margin-top: -(50/2)px;
}
```

this 50px can be varied according to your choice